# Pictures or images are overlaying Java

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I'm trying to make a calculator and here's my code so far. So my problem is that the results will overlap once I click on the next button. I have to input answers from the given answer and if the answer is correct then it will give me a green image and if it is wrong it will give me a red image. But then, then when I click on the next... the images are overlapping sometimes the numbers won't move. Please help.

```
    public Calculatorx() {
        con = getContentPane();
        con.setLayout(null);
        JLabel subTitle = new JLabel(" Elementary Math Tutor ");
        con.add(subTitle);
        subTitle.setBounds(150, 1, 200, 70);
        rand1 = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 9);
        rand2 = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * rand1);
        while (rand1 % rand2 != 0) {
            rand2 = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * rand1);
        }
        jbtadd1 = new JButton("" + rand1);
        jbtsub1 = new JButton("" + rand1);
        jbtmul1 = new JButton("" + rand1);
        jbtdiv1 = new JButton("" + rand1);
        con.add(jbtadd1);
        con.add(jbtsub1);
        con.add(jbtmul1);
        con.add(jbtdiv1);
        jbtadd1.setBounds(50, 50, 50, 50);
        jbtsub1.setBounds(50, 120, 50, 50);
        jbtmul1.setBounds(50, 190, 50, 50);
        jbtdiv1.setBounds(50, 260, 50, 50);
        JLabel plus = new JLabel(plusIcon);
        JLabel minus = new JLabel(minusIcon);
        JLabel mul = new JLabel(mulIcon);
        JLabel div = new JLabel(divIcon);
        con.add(plus);
        con.add(minus);
        con.add(mul);
        con.add(div);
        plus.setBounds(100, 50, 150, 50);
        minus.setBounds(80, 120, 200, 50);
        mul.setBounds(60, 190, 250, 50);
        div.setBounds(40, 260, 300, 50);
        jbtadd2 = new JButton("" + rand2);
        jbtsub2 = new JButton("" + rand2);
        jbtmul2 = new JButton("" + rand2);
        jbtdiv2 = new JButton("" + rand2);
        con.add(jbtadd2);
        con.add(jbtsub2);
        con.add(jbtmul2);
        con.add(jbtdiv2);
        jbtadd2.setBounds(250, 50, 50, 50);
        jbtsub2.setBounds(250, 120, 50, 50);
        jbtmul2.setBounds(250, 190, 50, 50);
        jbtdiv2.setBounds(250, 260, 50, 50);
        JLabel equal1 = new JLabel(equalIcon);
        JLabel equal2 = new JLabel(equalIcon);
        JLabel equal3 = new JLabel(equalIcon);
        JLabel equal4 = new JLabel(equalIcon);
        con.add(equal1);
        con.add(equal2);
        con.add(equal3);
        con.add(equal4);
        equal1.setBounds(330, 40, 50, 50);
        equal2.setBounds(330, 110, 50, 50);
        equal3.setBounds(330, 180, 50, 50);
        equal4.setBounds(330, 250, 50, 50);
        addAnswer = new JTextField();
        subAnswer = new JTextField();
        mulAnswer = new JTextField();
        divAnswer = new JTextField();
        con.add(addAnswer);
        con.add(subAnswer);
        con.add(mulAnswer);
        con.add(divAnswer);

        addAnswer.setBounds(410, 50, 50, 50);
        subAnswer.setBounds(410, 120, 50, 50);
        mulAnswer.setBounds(410, 190, 50, 50);
        divAnswer.setBounds(410, 260, 50, 50);
        JButton Check = new JButton("CHECK");
        JButton Next = new JButton("NEXT");
        JButton Exit = new JButton("EXIT");
        con.add(Check);
        con.add(Next);
        con.add(Exit);
        Check.setBounds(235, 330, 75, 30);
        Next.setBounds(320, 330, 65, 30);
        Exit.setBounds(395, 330, 65, 30);



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your Next action listener throws an NullPointerException because the 4 operand variables are not initilized. Please add the following code at the beginning of your Calculatorx constructor:

```
 operand1 = new JLabel();
 operand2 = new JLabel();
 operand3 = new JLabel();
 operand4 = new JLabel();
```

To solve the issue of your overlapping icons insert the following line at the beginning of the Check Action Listener in the actionPerformed method:

```
 Check.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            con.repaint();              
            ....
```

Also the following 2 lines are probably not needed:

```
 con.add(operand4);
 operand4.setBounds(520, 260, 50, 50);
```

As a general advice you should always use lower case letters for objects name. Only class names begin with an upper case letter (as well as constants)

Comment: What do you mean by con.repaint();?

Comment: it tells the container **con** to repaint itself. Executing it before the other code in the actionPeformed method "clears" the previously shown images from the container and that leeds to no more overlapping.